# More prominently display send-receive error

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

Fairly frequently, Outlook has send-receive issues, typically due to disconnecting from the server (VPN, moving from floor to floor, etc.).  I'm not worried about fixing these, I know how to (restart Outlook).

However, I don't get a very prominent notification when they occur.  The "SEND/RECEIVE ERROR" notification is this little bit on the very bottom of the screen, in a place I don't really pay any attention to, except when I'm wondering why people aren't responding to my emails... and my outbox is not at the top of my fairly large list of folders.  I typically have the Inbox expanded, and that knocks the Outbox off the screen entirely.

Is there a way to configure Outlook to give me a more forceful notification when something's sitting in my Outbox?  Failing that, is there a way to force Outbox to sit at the top of the list of folders (above Inbox)?

Comment: One option would be to add the outbox to your favorite folders so it's at the top of the list. Another option would be to use Redemption to extend Outlook and code a hook for sending errors.

Comment: Ah, okay - and I just realized I could drag it up (silly me for not trying that).  Will do that for now, hopefully someone else will have a way to make the errors notify me more clearly!